# How to view Excel source code in an Excel file with Modals

Tags: excel, excel-2013

I have developer toolbar enabled and have macros enabled.

However the excel file I want to open immediately opens a modal popup which prevents any other options from being clicked. I can navigate the other modals from that modal window but I can't view the source code of it because the modal window is open all the time it is impossible to click on the developer toolbar to view the VBA code. Even the VBA shortcut Alt-F11 doesn't work while the modal window is showing.

Comment: If its a standard UserForm shown by the `Workbook_Open` event, hold down `Shift` while you open the file,  This should disable the event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the following worked:

> If its a standard UserForm shown by the Workbook_Open event, hold down Shift while you open the file, This should disable the event.
>
> – chris neilsen Mar 29 '16 at 0:28